# 20 images get uploaded instead of 30

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, guzzle, laravel-7, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel with the plugin to create files in AWS S3 (`league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`).

I'm having an issue where:

- I have an API call with a method in a controller that receives an array of files.
- The method reads all the files and uploads them to S3.
- For some reason, if I send more than 20 files, only 20 files get uploaded to AWS S3.

Since the plugin for AWS S3 uses Guzzle under the hood, I was thinking it could be related to a timeout or maximum number of calls to be made within a certain period.

Any ideas of what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a limitation in your php.ini file.

When you install php this is the default configuration:

```
; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Try changing this limit and then restarting your server (apache, nginx, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Please verify your php.ini file with below two values

Please try increasing "upload_max_filesize"

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

> upload_max_filesize = 2M

Also check "max_file_uploads" is greater than 20.

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request

> max_file_uploads = 20